# Несколько вопросов про iframe приложение для Вконтакте

Tags: вконтакте, iframe

Я сделал свое первое iframe приложение для Вконтакте, которое просто открывает в iframe обычный сайт и выглядит вот так:

[image: iframe приложение для Вконтакте]

Однако у меня появилось несколько вопросов на которые я еще не нашел ответы:

1. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда любой пользователь социальной сети Вконтакте автоматически регистрировался в игре и автоматически входил под сгенерированным логином и паролей?
2. Если это возможно, как это можно реализовать? Где можно прочитать об этом?
3. Что еще из функциональности Вконтакте для iframe приложений Вы бы рекомендовали мне реализовать?

Заранее спасибо, за ответы. Жду Ваших советов и Вашей помощи.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что нужно разбираться именно с OAuth авторизацией? Я прав?

Comment: А зачем весь этот геморой с регистрацией? Просто заносите при первом запуске в базу ID ВК и всё, а в дальнейшем получайте с него всё что хотите.

Comment: @eprivalov1 а травиан официальную версию какую-то допиливаешь, или нашел какую-то версию, и пытаешься свой сервер поднять?

Answer (score 2):

1. Да
2. Надо читать документации API контакта. Можно при регистрации делать запрос авторизации и записывать id контакта, а при входе из приложения контакта id входящего передается, и по нему искать. Также можно это дело убрать в настройки, т.е. делать привязки.
3. Для начала убедитесь в том, Вы можете принимать пользователей по https, это обязательное требование vk.com.

Comment: Если зайти на сайт через https://, то он не открывается...

Comment: @eprivalov1 Для этого вам нужна поддержка SSH и заход через https. Или в инструкциях написать, как заходить в приложение, чтобы оно работало )